# Custom time data being truncated in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've written some VBA to read race results from an Excel 2010 spreadsheet running on Windows 10 Home and then output it as XML.

If the race times are formatted with the custom format `h:mm:ss.0` then when read into a VBA string using this: `sTotalTime = Sheet3.Cells(iNumResults, 50).Value` then the hour gets dropped.

For example, a time of `1:39:55.3` in the spreadsheet is shown in the XML output and in the VBA Watch window as `39:55.3`

However, if the race times do NOT include the hour but are formatted as `mm:ss.0` they are read in and output correctly.  There is no manipulation occurring on the read data....it's simply stored in a string variable and then written out "as is".

I would appreciate any thoughts on why the time is being truncated and how to fix it.

Comment: Try `.Value2` maybe

Comment: Tried it - same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I can't duplicate your result: but I suggest you try

```
sTotalTime = Sheet3.Cells(iNumResults, 50).Text
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I tried that (and also Sheet3.Cells(iNumResults,50).Value2) and still get the truncation.

Comment: So what exactly does .Value2 show you? (after all that is what is really in the cell)

Comment: If I use .Value, .Text or .Value2, the result is the same:  a time of 01:39:55.3 in the cell in Excel (with the format of h:mm:ss.0 applied to it) is read in and displayed in the Watch window as 39:55.3

Comment: Usually times in Excel are stored as float numbers but displayed according to the applied cell format: but your times are not like that. How are the times entered/created? What do you see in Excel and VBA if you format as General? (should see 0.0693900462963 if its really a number)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here's the thing. I'm doing this as a volunteer to facilitate what is currently a tricky "business" problem in skiing in Australia. Most timing software produces results in a CSV format. Within the CSV file, the race times are either formatted with Custom mm:ss.0 or h:mm:ss.0 depending on the magnitude of the slowest time. So to make the process easy I've solutioned this where they COPY and PASTE SPECIAL the results from the CSV file into my VBA enabled Excel workbook. Whilst the format is retained, and the time appears correct, when read into a variable it's truncated

Comment: I still cannot duplicate your result. Maybe we are using "format" in different senses. I am talking about Excel cell formatting (Home->Cells->Format->Format Cells). What happens if you format the cells as Text before pasteing the data? And why use Paste Special?

Comment: Nope, we're using "Format" in the same sense. I'm using "Paste Special" so as to retain the formatting applied to the source data. Everything works just fine UNLESS the time exceeds 1 hour even though the format applied is apparently correct (h:mm:ss.0).  If formatted as "General" I see "0.0693900462962963" which appears to be correct as a Float representation of the time. For some reason, the hour is being truncated.

Comment: Still cannot duplicate your problem result. CSV does not have a format, its just text. Try applying an excel custom format of [h]:mm:ss.0 after either  copy paste or just opening the CSV file

Comment: Charles - thanks for the suggestion. I did as you suggested, and applied the custom format directly to the data in the VBA enabled workbook. The same behaviour still occurs:  a time of 1:39:55.3 is output as 39:55.3